# Getting timestamp of first day of month

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=fff52dd5a0d64b13ff53781e37d832f2)**

```
CREATE TABLE PaL (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO PaL
(event_date)
VALUES 

('2020-01-01'),
('2020-02-05'),
('2020-03-20'),
('2020-04-15'),
('2020-05-11'),
('2020-06-18'),
('2020-07-19'),
('2020-12-31');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
first_date_of_the_month     first_timestamp_of_the_month
2020-01-01                      2020-01-01 00:00:00
2020-02-01                      2020-02-01 00:00:00
2020-03-01                      2020-03-01 00:00:00
2020-04-01                      2020-04-01 00:00:00
2020-05-01                      2020-05-01 00:00:00
2020-06-01                      2020-06-01 00:00:00
2020-07-01                      2020-07-01 00:00:00
2020-12-01                      2020-12-01 00:00:00
```

---

I want to extract the `first date` and `first timestamp` of each `event_date` in the table. 
I am doing this with the below query:

```
SELECT 
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(pl.event_date), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AS first_date_of_the_month,
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(pl.event_date), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL -1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS first_timestamp_of_the_month
FROM PaL pl
```

---

However, `HeidiSQL` is somehow interpeting the timestamp as value and not as a `TIMESTAMP` format.

[image]

How do I need to change the query so it displays the result as `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: If by `TIMESTAMP` you mean Unix style timestamps (seconds since 1970), you need to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, but note, in many versions of MySQL this is 32 bit not 64 bit so expires in 2038. If you want it 64bit, you need to calculate it yourself. I use this `((to_days(expiry_dt)-719528)*86400+time_to_sec(expiry_dt))` (for the field `expiry_dt`)

Comment: If you are using date formats, you can use day `00` to mean before the month styart, as in `my_date >= "2021-03-00"` to mean everything in this month - its basically the same as `my_date >= "2021-03-01 00:00:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
       DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS first_date_of_the_month,
       DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AS first_timestamp_of_the_month
FROM PaL
```

> `HeidiSQL` is somehow interpeting the timestamp as value and not as a `TIMESTAMP` format.

This is client problem.

MySQL's datatype system is soft, i.e. each value is converted to needed datatype according to current datatype context implicitly. But you may use correct final context or excplicit final CAST.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=21a7d3fccaca1329ef8e1797d366c5a6

Comment: `concat(substr(date(now()),1,7),"-01 00:00:00")` <- start of this month - MySQL will automatically convert strings & dates, if you compare the two

Comment: @James You use 3 functions. I use one function only.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert to strings to accomplish this.  It is simple enough with basic date functions:

```
SELECT event_date + interval (1 - day(event_date)) day as first_date_of_the_month,
       timestamp(event_date + interval (1 - day(event_date)) day) as first_timestamp_of_the_month
FROM PaL pl;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=0400fe01b8f17e1b741e46c0c695638b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: `event_date + interval (1 - day(event_date))` <- won't this retain the original time element from the `event_date` ?

Comment: @James . . . `date` does not have a time element in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Gotta chime in here....  The way I prefer in MySQL, the way that uses the inbuilt [LAST_DAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function, is this:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(event_date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

For what it's worth the string constants `2021-03-13 00:00:00` and the shorter `2021-03-13` have *precisely the same meaning* when used as `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` values. There's little need for a separate `first_timestamp_of_the_month` value.

It works in Oracle too.  In SQL Server, it's EOMONTH(). postgreSQL, not so much.

Comment: It would be nice for future database programmers if the vendors could standardize a minimal set of date-arithmetic functions, eh?